# Propiedad "types" en package.json no funciona correctamente

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, ts

Estoy pasando la documentación de mis códigos a un archivo de definiciones `.d.ts`.
Mi problema es que cuando pongo la ruta del archivo de definiciones en mi `package.json`, no funciona.

Cuando pongo mi archivo de definiciones junto a mi archivo `index.js`, los types si los detecta y se muestran en vsc, pero en cambio si muevo mi archivo de definiciones a su carpeta (`@types`) y le pongo la ruta en el `package.json` en la propiedad `types (alias typings)` no funciona.

Esta es la estructura que usé hasta el momento:

[image: structure]

Y este es mi archivo `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "typings": "./@types/index.d.ts"
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes el mismo problema usando "types" en lugar de "typings"?

Comment: @PabloLozano si que lo he hecho, de hecho, `typings` es el alias de `types` por lo que no debería de haber ningún tipo de problema con eso.